# Application crash - debug says "objc_msgsend"

Tags: objective-c

I have started a 2d tile based game for iphone , i will jump directly to the class's i have and the issue. i have totally 2 class for now Tile , Table , and Base main class
Tile

```
`@interface Tile : NSObject {
 CCSprite *sprite;
 CCSprite *outline;
 int row,column;
 BOOL highLight;
}
```

@property (nonatomic , retain)CCSprite *sprite;
@property (nonatomic , retain)CCSprite *outline;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) int row, column;
@property (nonatomic , readwrite)BOOL highLight;
-(id) initWithSpriteName: (NSString*)argSpriteName Row:(int)argRow Column:(int)argColumn Position:(CGPoint)argPosition;

@end`

Table

```
`@interface Table : NSObject {
 CCLayer *layer;
 CGSize  size;
 NSArray *icons;
 NSMutableArray *content;
```

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *content;
@property(nonatomic, retain) CCLayer *layer;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGSize size;
-(id) initWithTableSize:(CGSize)argSize; 
-(void)render;
-(Tile *) objectAtX: (int) x Y: (int) y;
`

Calling Class (Main)

```
@interface HelloWorld : CCLayer
{
 CGSize  size;
 Table  *tableLayer;
}
@property (retain) Table  *tableLayer;
```

Implementation

```
-(id) init
{
 // always call "super" init
 // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
 if( (self=[super init] )) {
  ......
                tableLayer = [[Table alloc] initWithTableSize:CGSizeMake(4,7) ];
  tableLayer.layer = self;
  [tableLayer render];
  self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
  self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;
  [self schedule:@selector(render:)];
  [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:(1.0 / 30)];
```

}
 return self;
}

.
.
.

-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint touchCorrected;
    touchCorrected.x = location.x;
    touchCorrected.y = 480 - location.y;
    int x = (int)(touchCorrected.x/48);
    int y = (int)(touchCorrected.y/48);
    printf("X = %d Y = %d \n",x,y);
    if (x!=0 && y!=0) {
   Tile *tile = [tableLayer objectAtX:(1) Y:(1)];
   [tile setHighLight:YES];
     }
}

My program gets crashed when calling the following statement inside the touch end call back

```
   Tile *tile = [tableLayer objectAtX:(1) Y:(1)];
```

I have read few blogs but really having tough time to understand the concept behind messaging , could you please explain me what is cause for the application crash ends "objc_msgsend".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is most likely a memory management error.  I would check out [Hamster Emporium's blog post called "So you crashed in objc_msgSend()"](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html).  It's very helpful.

Comment: As a side note, Hampster Emporium is written by Greg Parker, one of the (quite brilliant) Objective-C runtime engineers at Apple. In otherwords, go read his blog!

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I have seen in many forums  people are referring to Hampster Emporium. I read three times the truth is since I'm a beginner  his writing was well advanced. I getting more doubts now , i will keep posting my queries. thanks for your help.