# Objective C - Assign, Copy, Retain

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, memory-management, attributes

I'm new to Objective C. I have basic knowledge in C, including the concept of pointers. I have two basic questions:

1. Can someone explain the difference between assign,copy, and retain with some analogy?
2. How do you handle a function which returns pointer variable, and how do you perform messaging through a return pointer?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**Updated Answer for Changed Documentation**

The information is now spread across several guides in the documentation. Here's a list of required reading:

- [Cocoa Core Competencies: Declared property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DeclaredProperty.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH13-SW1)
- [Programming with Objective-C: Encapsulating Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW1)
- [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)
- [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide: Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW1)

The answer to this question now depends entirely on whether you're using an ARC-managed application (the modern default for new projects) or forcing manual memory management.

**Assign vs. Weak** - Use **assign** to set a property's pointer to the address of the object without retaining it or otherwise curating it; use **weak** to have the property point to nil automatically if the object assigned to it is deallocated. In most cases you'll want to use **weak** so you're not trying to access a deallocated object (illegal access of a memory address - "`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`") if you don't perform proper cleanup.

**Retain vs. Copy** - Declared properties use **retain** by default (so you can simply omit it altogether) and will manage the object's reference count automatically whether another object is assigned to the property or it's set to nil; Use **copy** to automatically send the newly-assigned object a `-copy` message (which will create a copy of the passed object and assign that copy to the property instead - useful (even required) in some situations where the assigned object might be modified after being set as a property of some other object (which would mean that modification/mutation would apply to the property as well).

Comment: Thanks dude I read the basics from Apple Dev , on my present development Having a hard time in memory management "crashed in objc_msgSend()" So i just thought of revising my understanding on properties.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506205/application-crash-debug-says-objc-msgsend

Comment: Just a heads up, the link into the answer goes to a generic "Page not found" on apples site. Then it redirects to the "Mac Developer Library"  This SO answer has useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255861/property-and-retain-assign-copy-nonatomic

Comment: Kind of a difficult one to update because the documentation has changed and it's no longer in one convenient place. Feedback sent to Apple doc team.

Answer (score 34):

The [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html) from the iOS Reference Library has basics of assign, copy, and retain with analogies and examples.

> **copy**
>   Makes a copy of an object, and returns it with retain count of 1.
>   If you copy an object, you own the copy. This applies to any method that contains the word copy where “copy” refers to the object being returned.
>
> **retain** Increases the retain count of an object by 1. Takes ownership of
>   an object.
>
> **release** Decreases the retain count of an object by 1. Relinquishes
>   ownership of an object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Could you please explain 
1.ClassA have a  property called - (Class B*)functionName; 
2.ClassB have method – (void)setHeight;
3.ClassC interface  I have declared ClassA *tempA as retain.
4.Class C implementation in the constructor I have this statement  ClassB *tempB = tempA.functionName; 
5.When I try to send a message (tempB. setHeight;)  on the next line of tempB initialization my program works fine.

Comment: 6.putting the same statement(tempB. setHeight;) into some function and calling the same function my program get Crashed in objc_msgSend().

Answer (score 10):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First",@"Second", nil];
NSMutableArray *copiedArray = [array mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *retainedArray = [array retain];

[retainedArray addObject:@"Retained Third"];
[copiedArray addObject:@"Copied Third"];

NSLog(@"array = %@",array);
NSLog(@"Retained Array = %@",retainedArray);
NSLog(@"Copied Array = %@",copiedArray);

array = (
    First,
    Second,
    "Retained Third"
)
Retained Array = (
    First,
    Second,
    "Retained Third"
)
Copied Array = (
    First,
    Second,
    "Copied Third"
)
```

Comment: A surrounding explanation would seriously improve your answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. assign

   - assign is a default property attribute
   - assign is a property attribute tells the compiler how to synthesize the property’s setter implementation
2. copy:

   - copy is required when the object is mutable
   - copy returns an object which you must explicitly release (e.g., in dealloc) in non-garbage collected environments
   - you need to release the object when finished with it because you are retaining the copy
3. retain:

   - specifies the new value should be sent “-retain” on assignment and the old value sent “-release”
   - if you write retain it will auto work like strong
   - Methods like “alloc” include an implicit “retain”