# Difference between retain and copy?

Tags: objective-c, reference, copy, retain, counting

What exactly is the difference between retain and copy? what is its significance on reference counting?

I know that when an object is allocated using alloc/retain, reference count goes up by one.
so how about using copy?

Another question relating to this is, the difference between using
@property(nonatomic, retain)  and @property(nonatomic,copy)?

Comment: You haven't accepted any of the answers. You should choose one. :)

Answer (score 10):

retain -- is done on the created object, it just increase the reference count.

copy -- create a new object

Comment: copy also increase retrain count

Comment: @rithik : when new object is created retain count will be 1.

Comment: copy doesn't always create a new object

Answer (score 3):

Answering your question to the best of my knowledge.
First, What exactly is the difference between retain and copy? what is its significance on reference counting?

retain - "Specifies that retain should be invoked on the object upon assignment. ... The previous value is sent a release message." So you can imagine assigning an NSString instance (which is an object and which you probably want to retain). So the retain count goes up by 1.

copy - "Specifies that a copy of the object should be used for assignment. ... The previous value is sent a release message." Basically same as retain, but sending -copy rather than -retain. if i remember correctly the count will go up by 1 too.

ok, now going into more detail.

Property attributes are special keywords to tell compiler how to generate the getters and setters. Here you specify two property attributes: nonatomic, which tells the compiler not to worry about multithreading, and retain, which tells the compiler to retain the passed-in variable before setting the instance variable.

In other situations, you might want to use the “assign” property attribute instead of retain, which tells the compiler NOT! to retain the passed-in variable. Or perhaps the “copy” property attribute, which makes a copy of the passed-in variable before setting.

I hope that helps. I found another post in here that might help you too.

[Objective C - Assign, Copy, Retain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510913/objective-c-assign-copy-retain)

Cheers!
Jose

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, **`copy`** creates a new object which has the same value with the original object, and sets the reference count of the new created object to 1 (By the way, reference count of the original object is not affected).

However, **`copy`** is equivalent to **`retain`** for immutable object, which JUST increate the reference count of the original object by 1.