# iOS and memory management

Tags: ios, memory-management, copy, retain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between retain and copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827223/difference-between-retain-and-copy)

I'm learning iOS development right now and I don't understand the memory management very well,
I have read the guide Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide in the apple develop center, but still have questions. The most important question I want to know is: What's the difference between `copy` and `retain` when define a property of a class? Thank you!

Comment: You might want to re-read the guidelines. The differences between retain and copy are pretty well documented.

Comment: Hi, i  am not giving the your answer bcoz mattjgalloway has already given a link for that. I am giving you the link for Handling Memory Management by My Project Lead. see [this](http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/efficient-memory-handling-in-uiviewcontroller-part-1/) and [this one](http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/efficient-memory-handling-in-uiviewcontroller-part-2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a thousand answers to this on SO! However, the first thing to understand is that when you define a `@property` you are issuing a directive to the compiler of your application and the `retain`/`copy` (and all the other things you see in the brackets) are instructions to the compiler on how to follow the directive.

`@property` essentially means - Please Mr. Compiler, make me some accessor methods (getters & setters).

So, `retain` & `copy` are instructions to the compiler which tell it how to operate inside those getter / setter accessors.

`copy` means - when I say `[myClass setMyProperty:propertyReference]` - I want the class to make a copy of the property. A complete new instance of the property. Therefore the copy inside the class is not affected by external shenanigans going on outside of the class.

`retain` means - I want the class to remember the exact instance of the property I am setting. NOT a new instance at all. In this case, when that instance changes, your class will know the up to date state of the property.