# Xcode Objective-C all properties displaying a warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, automatic-ref-counting

This is really strange. All of the sudden my xcode project is showing warnings for almost all properties I have declared.

I'm building an app for Mac OS with Xcode 5.1.1.

Most properties I'm not specifying any attributes as I'm aware the default is a strong reference. But now all of the sudden I get warnings for everything.

What would I have done to trigger this? Up until a few minutes ago these warnings would never show up. I don't want to have to declare the attributes for every property - only the ones I don't want to be strong references.

It doesn't give me warnings for properties that are implicitly assign or atomic.

I've attached a screenshot.

Any ideas? Is there a build setting that accidentally got turned on?

Could there have been something in a single file that started triggering all these warnings? Like some kind of circular reference?

Edit: This is an ARC project.

Edit: I found the source of the problem: I have a non-arc file (-fno-objc-arc) including an arc file. Anyone know how to handle this properly?

[image]

Comment: You have to give a property a retain or copy attribute.

Comment: this hasn't happened to me before. I'm looking at a different project that I built and it doesn't give me all these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the property either `retain`, `copy`, `weak`, or `strong`, if it's an Objective C object and you're not using ARC. See this question for more info: [Objective C - Assign, Copy, Retain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510913/objective-c-assign-copy-retain)

Comment: I'm using arc though.

Comment: @gngrwzrd give it strong then

Comment: @Milo but `strong` is the default for an object property under ARC.

Answer (score 0):

In your build settings, check the `Other Warning Flags` option and see if something is in there. Check the other flags options as well just in case.

You may have something such as `-Weverything`, or `-Wobjc-property-no-attribute` that is turning on additional warnings that you don't have on by default, or in your other project.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had included an ARC file in a non-ARC file (-fno-objc-arc). The file that was included was the AppDelegate.h file, which included a bunch of other stuff. So when the non-ARC file was being compiled, it included all these ARC files which then triggered warnings.