# What is diff Retain and Copy in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Hi i am Android developer and recently i moved to i-phone developing and i am present learning about memory management,I read so many documents about memory management but i have little confusion about below statement what happen when we use **retain** and **copy** and **strong** and **weak** for below statement's

### code1:-

```
NSString* name = [[NSString alloc]init];--->retain count 1

[name retain]

[name copy]

[name release]
```

### code2:-

```
@propery(nonautomic,strong)NSString*name;
@propery(nonautomic,weak)NSString*name;
@propery(nonautomic,retain)NSString*name;
@propery(nonautomic,copy)NSString*name;
```

Comment: when you call retain , retain count increase by 1. When you copy it, the retain count stays same. When you release it, the retain count decrease by 1.

Comment: then what is diff b/w retain and copy?

Comment: As I said, retain transfers the ownership of the object, if you assign [name retain] to another object B, then  you are transferring the ownership of name to B, in this case you need to control the memory retain count for B instead of name. IF you use copy, then you are not transferring the ownership, you still need to control the retain count for name!

Comment: can u exaplain with some example please

Comment: pls refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510913/objective-c-assign-copy-retain

Comment: And [NSString property: copy or retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain).

Comment: `retain`does not transfer the ownership, but adds an ownership. @TejaNandamuri

Comment: thanks for clarifying , then what transfers the ownership ? @AminNegm-Awad

Comment: In MRR you can "transfer" the ownership by retaining the new reference (=adding an ownership) *plus* releasing the old one (relinquish an ownership), what dos obviously nothing over all. However, there is no reason to look at it this way, because every reference should be viewed separately. (Maybe you got confused with bridging.)

Comment: Also, please use "iPhone". and not "i-phone". Thanks.